# what order should I be replacing floor and drywall in?

Tags: drywall, flooring

I'm replacing particle board panels with drywall (after adding some insulation) and removing the laminate floor and the carpet beneath with proper subfloor.
I've got the acoustic tiles down from the ceiling, the particle board off the studs, and will be pulling the laminate and carpet off next.

My question is, what order should I be doing the things in? Floor first or Drywall first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the order that works well for me.

1. Subfloor
2. Framing & Drywall
3. Underlayment
4. Door Casings
5. Finished Floor (undercut the casings to the finished floor height)
6. Baseboards (If you are carpeting put baseboards down before carpet.)